# Running python script in terminal only starts interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

I'm trying to run a python script in a terminal in Ubuntu, every time I try - the interpreter just starts.

Example:

```
michael@michael-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/pb_cli/pb_cli$ python move_users.py --input=users.txt --username --source_account=1 --destination_account=2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And move_users.py

```
"""Move Users.

Usage:

    move_users.py --input=<input_file> (--id | --email | --username) --source_account=<source_account> --destination_account=<destination_account>

"""

from common.docopt import docopt

from common import utilities as utilities

import time
import fnmatch
import subprocess
import os
import json
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':



    #Get Arguments

    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='1.0.0rc2')

    ....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happen if you issue the following command? `python -c "print('hello')"`

Comment: hello is echo'd back to the terminal

Comment: What happen if you issue the following command? `echo print 1 > t.py ; python t.py`  If this echo back 1, then the problem maybe is caused by the unexposed code that does something like `import code; code.interact()`

Comment: I'm actually interested in the lines after getting the arguments, the `....`.